# Back scatter imaging

Tags: radiation

backscattering is already part of Compton scattering for X-rays.
Compton scattering is directly proportional to the density of the material i.e. as the density increases as the Compton scattering increases.
This should suggest that high-density materials would backscatter more radiation than lower-density materials, but that does not actually happen!!!
What actually happens is that low-density material backscatters more than the higher-density material and I cannot understand why??